# How to add a value manually to DataReader in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am copying sample.csv file's content into the new.csv file. But I need to add additional column in new.csv file which holds the default value as "Yes" for each row that exists in old file. Here is the code I have written.

```
  Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")      
  Dim ioLine As String
  Dim ioLines As String      
  ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine     
  ioLines = "ID","Name","Number","Amount","Copied"
  ioLines &= vbCrLf & ioLine 
  While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine         
    ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
  End While     
  Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")     
  ioWriter.WriteLine(ioLines)     
  ioFile.Close()     
  ioWriter.Close()
```

The first four columns ID,Name,Number,Amount are present in sample.csv. I am adding additional column Copied which should be "Yes" for each row. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append the value to the line string in your loop.

```
While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine         
    ioLine &= ",Yes"  
    ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
End While
```

**EDIT**: This should account for your loop condition.

```
  While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
    if ioLine <> "" then 
      ioLine &= ",Yes"
      ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine   
    end if   
  End While
```

Thanks for the assist, @D..

Comment: I tried this one, but application is not responding because "Yes" is being written even underneath the data. For example if i have 100 rows, for 100 rows it is working fine. But from 101th row Yes is coming in every cell.

Comment: Why we need to check `if ioLine <> ""` when it is the While looping condition? Is that redundant action?

Comment: @Dee Jay: It is not redundant--its value changed in the first line of the loop. We are checking it before we operate on it and use its value in the rest of the loop, because those are invalid operations if we are at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply append the value inside the existing loop like:

```
  While Not ioLine = ""         
    ioLine = ioFile.ReadLine
    if ioLine <> "" then ioLine &= ",Yes"
    ioLines = ioLines & vbCrLf & ioLine      
  End While
```

Comment: I tried this one, but application is not responding because "Yes" is being written even underneath the data. For example if i have 100 rows, for 100 rows it is working fine. But from 101th row Yes is coming in every cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Test()
    Dim ioFile As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\sample.csv")

    Dim content As String
    content = ioFile.ReadToEnd
    ioFile.Close()

    Dim ContentArray() As String
    ContentArray = Split(content, vbCrLf, -1, CompareMethod.Binary)

    Dim current As String
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    sb.Append("ID,Name,Number,Amount,Copied")

    For Each current In ContentArray
        sb.Append(vbCrLf & current & ",Yes")
    Next

    Dim ioWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\new.csv")
    ioWriter.Write(sb.ToString)

    ioWriter.Close()

End Sub
```